# How to analyze the abnormal trajectory of the vehicle?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-analysis

I use this code to mark the latitude and longitude of the vehicle with red points on the map:

```
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def testPlot():
    df = pd.read_csv(r'device_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
    gb = df.groupby(['device_id', 'upload_time_1'])
    sub_dataframe_list = []
    for i in gb.indices:
        sub_df = pd.DataFrame(gb.get_group(i))
        sub_dataframe_list.append(sub_df)
    for sub_dataframe in sub_dataframe_list:
        device_id = sub_dataframe['device_id'].iloc[0]
        upload_time_1 = sub_dataframe['upload_time_1'].iloc[0]
        sub_dataframe = sub_dataframe.sort_values(by=['upload_time'])
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
        m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=77, llcrnrlat=14, urcrnrlon=140, urcrnrlat=51, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45,lon_0=100)
        m.readshapefile(r'E:/test_opencv/gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1', 'states', drawbounds=True)
        x = sub_dataframe['longitude'].tolist()
        y = sub_dataframe['latitude'].tolist()
        lats = y
        lons = x
        m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
        m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#ffffff')
        x, y = m(lons, lats)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=1)
        plt.savefig(r'all_device_data_image/'+str(device_id)+'_'+str(upload_time_1)+'.png')
        plt.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testPlot()
```

The normal vehicle trajectory is like this, the latitude and longitude are continuous：

[image]

But the abnormal vehicle trajectory is like this, the latitude and longitude are not continuous, it is very sparse:
[image]

[image]

If the abnormal trajectory is supplemented with green latitude and longitude, it is a normal trajectory, like this:
[image]
[image]

For my question, how can I judge the vehicle trajectory is abnormal? Statistics or machine learning or deep learning can be used, but I don't know which algorithm can do it. If I don’t use statistics or machine learning or deep learning, what should I do? Determine the average and standard deviation of latitude and longitude?

I think it is not a good idea to use the average and standard deviation of latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hi! It may be beneficial to think of this like a clustering problem. If there is a nearly continuous trajectory, the right clustering algorithm should return a single cluster. If there are large gaps between trajectories, it would return something other than 1. Here's a link which may help you here: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-iot-gps-trajectory-clustering-and-geospatial-clustering-daba8da8c41e

Comment: This is helpful.